# How to get only new rows from Google Sheets spreadsheet with Python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, etl

Let's assume I have a spreadsheet with data and a manually launched Python script, that loads it and sends it to Google BigQuery.

Let's assume at 11:00 I have 10 rows and my script reads them and sends to GBQ.

Then at 18:00, I have 15 rows. I want to read and send only those 5 new rows.
What is the optimal way to do it with Python?

My ideas are:

1. Save an index of the last loaded row and read it the next time the script is launched. While it is fairly simple to do, I do not feel like this is the right and optimal solution to the problem.
2. Somehow get the last time when the script was running and load only those rows, whose insertion time is bigger, than scripts' run time. While this sounds better to me, I haven't found a way to do it.

Can you, please, suggest your ideas or give some assessment of mine?

Answer (score 1):

**Your ideas are on the right track!**

Using an Index or Marker Row:
This approach involves keeping track of the last processed row using an index or marker row within your Google Sheets spreadsheet. When your script runs, it reads the data starting from the next row after the marker row. This method is simple and effective, but it does require modifying the spreadsheet by adding an index or marker row.

Timestamp-Based Approach:
This approach involves adding a timestamp column to your spreadsheet. Whenever a new row is added, the timestamp for that row is automatically set to the current time. When your script runs, it can query the spreadsheet for rows that have a timestamp greater than the last run time of the script. This approach doesn't require modifying the existing rows but does require that you have a timestamp column.

Here's a more detailed implementation of the timestamp-based approach:

Add a Timestamp Column:
Add a column to your Google Sheets spreadsheet to store timestamps. Whenever a new row is added, the timestamp for that row should be automatically set to the current time. You can use Google Sheets formulas to achieve this.

Record Last Run Time:
In your Python script, you can save the timestamp of the last time the script was run. You can store this timestamp in a file or a configuration setting. This will be used as a reference point to identify new rows.

Query New Rows:
When the script runs again, it can query the Google Sheets spreadsheet for rows that have timestamps greater than the recorded last run time. This can be achieved using the Google Sheets API with Python.

Update Last Run Time:
After processing the new rows, update the recorded last run time to the current time. This ensures that the next time the script runs, it will only process rows added after this updated timestamp.

*This approach is robust and doesn't require modifying the existing data within the spreadsheet. It also ensures that you capture new rows accurately based on their insertion time.*

In terms of efficiency, both approaches have their trade-offs. The timestamp-based approach might be more reliable for capturing new data accurately, especially in scenarios where rows could be added between script runs. However, it does involve more API calls since you need to query based on timestamps. The index/marker row approach is simpler but requires additional management of the marker row within the spreadsheet.

**Hope I could help :)**